# How can I give access to my Chrome Extension content only to specific signed in users?

Tags: google-chrome-extension, oauth-2.0, google-signin

I'm creating a private Chrome Extension for the company where I work. I need users to sign in with their corporate Google account before to be able to access its content.

I've been reading about `Chrome Identity API` and `Google OAuth2` but I do not understand them at all, nor how to use them.

This is what I need. Between those two steps, I want user to be able to sign-in within a browser tab or the same extension popup window with the Google Sign-in service, and then access to the private content.

[image: concept]

Comment: Can you add any details like: code used, error problem encountered? [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) Show the community what you have tried.